# How to display the image, name and short description for a bundle product items

Tags: product-list, bundled-product, product-images

I need to display in a bundle product tab the image, name and short description for its items.

To do this for a grouped product items would be very simple, but for bundle products is different because the items are options rather than regular products so you don't have direct access to the product image, name, etc..

Answer (score 2):

You have access to the simple products in the templates `bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/*`. Those are the templates that render the simple products as options.

Each template contains this line `<?php $_selections = $_option->getSelections() ?>`.
Basically `$_selections` is an array of the simple products.